# CSS override line-height on word wrap

Tags: overriding, word-wrap, css

I have a list of links bound to a fairly narrow box; narrow enough for some links to wrap.

line-height is set to 30px, which is fine for the non-wrapped links; however, for a link whose text is long enough to force a line wrap, a 30px line-height is applied there as well, thus making it appear as if there are 2 links and not just a continuation of link text.

I'd like somehow (without js or on middleware end calc'ing string length) to get the wrapped link text to have a line-height of 10px or so to give visual impression of continuation and not separation.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`Line-height` is supposed to set the spacing between lines (particularly, when they wrap).  What you're probably looking for is `margin` on the `li` object.  If you set the `line-height` to the smaller value that you want when the lines wrap and set the `margin` to the value that you want in between the items, you should be good to go.

See if this does what you want:

```
li {
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    margin: 30px 0;
    line-height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Should get more rep for edge case solutions like this, but can only flag it answered 1X. Had to weak to get just right, but this is "the" way to go. It's interesting that line-height appears to be totally ignored when margin is the greater value.

Comment: Thanks for accepting!  The smaller `line-height` is ignored because `margin` and `line-height` are "collapsing" values.  The `line-height` value essentially puts a vertical margin on each line.  When two objects with vertical margin are adjacent, the smaller of the two margins is "collapsed" to zero, leaving only the larger value. Sorry, but I don't have a link to the spec for this.

Comment: Here's a site that seems to explain the collapsing margin concept fairly well:  [Collapsing Margins](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins)

Comment: the user didn't mention LI nor UL, why are you talking about it then? the real problem is that when a word breaks it does not have the same spacing as the line-height... am i missing something?

Comment: @Francesco You are correct, the OP did not specifically mention the `li` nor `ul` nor `ol` elements.  Since the question starts with "I have a list of links...," I guess I assumed that it was being done with the `ul` and `li` elements.  While the CSS provided in my answer is for the `li` element, it can be applied to other selectors, as well.  And based on the "accepted answer" checkmark and the up votes, it seems that the info has been pretty useful to a good number of people, despite my assumption of `li` being the element.  Does my assumption make my answer invalid?

Answer (score 5):

I would do it [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/thepriebe/kBKyD/1/)

```
li {
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin: 20px;
}

ul {
    width: 200px;
    border: solid 1px;
}
```

​

Or you could set the "first-line" pseudo element like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/thepriebe/kBKyD/)

```
li {
   padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    margin: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
li:first-line {
    margin: 10px;
    line-height: 10px;
}
ul {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: cool, but no dice, can't get default wrapped line-height changed. Ideally would have wrapped text appear right underneath with 5px spacing. I'll keep fiddling...

Comment: +1'd ya for the first-line option, my css fu is fairly weak, so nuggets like this are cool to come across ;-)